# How to re-order month column in df to match correct order of months in dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that consists of six columns - one of which is months. I want to re-order this column to match the order Months are in (Jan, Feb, March, April, May, June, etc..). I want to re-order all rows so that the data is also matching the new order based on changes in Months (i.e., V1 also moves with the re-order.

I was going to write a function that does this but Im sure there are easier ways (packages) to do so.

Here is my df:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Dataframe
df <- tribble(
    ~ID, ~Month, ~V1, ~V2, ~V3,
    1,  "Jan",   2,  3,  5,
    1,  "Feb",   3,  4,  6,
    1,  "Mar",   7,  8,  9,
    2,  "May",   1,  1,  1,
    2,  "Feb",   2,  3,  4,
    2,  "June",   7,  8,  8
)
df
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You'll have an easy time using akrun's suggestion or the dupe if you consistently use abbreviations or whole months. If you spell "June" out but use abbreviations for the rest, you'll have to adapt it a little bit as a special case. (I'd suggest `my_months = month.abb; my_months[6] = "June"`, and then using `my_months` instead of `month.abb` as in the answers.)

Answer (score 0):

An easier option is to `match` with the inbuilt 'month.abb'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    arrange(match(Month, month.abb))
```

If it is the full name instead of abbreviation, use `month.name`

```
df %>%
   arrange(match(Month, month.name))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work - when I do str(df) - the field 'Month' is a factor with 9 levels starting with April (keep in mind I am reading this in from an excel file - is the initial input my problem?

Comment: @Dinho Your example works for me.  Convert the `factor` column `to `character` and try `arrange(match(as.character(Month), month.abb))` assuming that the values are the same format

Comment: Im sorry - I was not clear in my input - it is the full name (January, February, March, etc...) Not abbreviated. I could potentially change the format in my initial input but idk if .abb will do the trick - should I do .name instead?

Comment: @Dinho IN that case instead of `month.abb` use `month.name`

Comment: @Dinho `month.name#
 [1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"     "May"       "June"      "July"      "August"    "September" "October"   "November"  "December"`

Comment: It still did not work - i converted the factor to character for the column 'Month', and used month.name - still did not output correctly. I think something is up with how I am reading in the csv file

Comment: @Dinho Check if the spelling is correct in your data.  I showed what values are there in 'month.name

Comment: @Dinho Can you show a small subset of your data with `dput`

Comment: dput(pop_df)
structure(list(Date.Ran = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
5L, 8L, 9L,), .Label = c("1/31/19", 
"2/28/19", "3/29/19", "4/30/19", "5/31/19", "6/28/19", "7/31/19", 
"8/30/19", "9/30/19"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2019L, 2019L, Month = c("January", 
"February", "March", "April", "June", "July", "May", "August", 
"September", "January", "February", "March", "April", "June", 
 row.names = c(NA, -496L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I had to remove a lot cause it was too big. This is a single line for each field from my df @akrun

Comment: @Dinho If you cut the structure, it won't work, You can do `dput(head(df, 10))`

Comment: @Dinho Also, based on the values you showed, it is matching with the `month.name`. May be check your `month.name` whether you have a different locale setting